# Jenkinsfile How do I use Array intro Array?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, pipeline, changelist

I'm using git changeLogSets plugin (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Changelog+Plugin)

I am trying to send mail using the plugin.

I want to send a single variable from the code.

Sample ; When I print the variable echo $ {exp}, I want it to print all the changes. How do I do this using array or a different alternative?

```
def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets
for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
    def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
    for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
        def entry = entries[j]
        echo "${entry.commitId} by ${entry.author} on ${new Date(entry.timestamp)}: ${entry.msg}"
        def files = new ArrayList(entry.affectedFiles)
        for (int k = 0; k < files.size(); k++) {
            def file = files[k]
            echo "  ${file.editType.name} ${file.path}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to do an array iterator in Groovy?

Comment: I want to transfer your change list to a single variable